# bind variable not declared error when using procedure in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

`

```
declare
    x number:=&x;
    y number:=&y;
    m number;
    s1 number;
    a1 number;
create or replace procedure z(x in number,y in number,m out number,s1 out number,a1 out number)
is
    begin
        if x<y
        then
            m:=x;
        else
            m:=y;
        end if;
        s1:=a+b;
        a1:s1/2;
end z;
/
begin
    z(x,y,m,s1,a1);
    dbms_output.put_line('Sum:'||sum1);
end;
/
/
```

I am trying to find the min sum and average of 2 numbers inputted by the user using pl/sql procedure

Answer (score 0):

You can't use *things* you didn't declare. Also, it is good to check for syntax errors.

See comments:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure z(x in number,y in number,m out number,s1 out number,a1 out number)
  2  is
  3      begin
  4          if x<y
  5          then
  6              m:=x;
  7          else
  8              m:=y;
  9          end if;
 10          s1:=x+y;          --> x and y    not a and b
 11          a1:=s1/2;         --> :=   not just :
 12  end z;
 13  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> declare
  2      x number:=&x;
  3      y number:=&y;
  4      m number;
  5      s1 number;
  6      a1 number;
  7  begin
  8      z(x,y,m,s1,a1);
  9      dbms_output.put_line('Sum:'||s1);     --> s1    not sum1
 10  end;
 11  /
Enter value for x: 3
Enter value for y: 5
Sum:8

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```